# If my Jenkinsfile is on repository itself, why should I specify the checkout command inside my Jenkinsfile?

Tags: version-control, jenkins-pipeline, checkout

I cannot figure out the philosophy of the paradigm "Pipeline script from SCM".
I create a job on Jenkins, where I specify a git repository, a branch and the name of the Jenkinsfile containing my pipeline.
I am supposed to specify, inside my Jenkinsfile, only the steps that I need to perform once the workspace is ready.
But if I omit the following step, the workspace is empty (even if I list current directory from my Jenkinsfile)

```
stage('checkout') {
 checkout scm  
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this by specific configuration of the Jenkins job or Jenkins itself?

Comment: Sometimes you need to deal with multiple repositories within the same Jenkins pipeline. Maybe this is a reason to have special DSL keyword to checkout code explicitly.

Comment: See if "Multi-branch pipeline" fits you, the checkout is automatic there unless you specify otherwise.